# Installation of Ubuntu over Linpus Lite

Tags: 14.04, acer

I am new to Ubuntu and would like to explore it. I have installed ubuntu by replacing Linpus Lite on my new laptop, by following the instructions on ubuntu download and installation page. However when the system restarts after installation, if the usb is connected it boots on ubuntu otherwise it goes back to Linpus Lite and hangs up.

Comment: was  the USB was connected during the installation?

Comment: Yes its was connected throughout. With a message to restart

Comment: did you select the installation destination? or purposedly installed Ubuntu on it?

Comment: I selected on option to uninstall Linpus Lite and install Ubuntu

Comment: then it might installed on your USB stick then. that make sense.

Comment: But i asked it to replace Linpus Lite which is installed on my laptop? How should i install it on my laptop

Comment: And how to separate hard drive into multiple portions?

Comment: It must be Linpus boot leftover on Linpus HDD. Your Ubuntu boot are on USB stick. So when USB unplugged it will read HDD boot sector.

Comment: you need to manully partition your HDD. there is option during the installation.

Comment: How should i remove Linpus completely, Please guide me through that

Comment: can anyone help!

Answer (score 1):

1. In the Boot set-up(F2), use "Legacy" and not "UEFI".
2. Ensure that the boot order is HDD first.
3. For Acer Laptops, ensure you enable the functioanlity of "F12" from the boot set-up.
4. Insert the USB stick. Boot from USB stick by pressing F12 and selecting your USB Stick name.
5. Install Ubuntu to your hard disk as you did, and it will work (hopefully!)